# Separate holomorphicity implies holomorphicity on analytic varieties

Tags: real-analysis, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, analytic-functions

Suppose that $M$ and $N$ are two complex analytic varities and suppose that $f\colon M\times N \to \mathbb{C}$ is a map. Further assume that $f$ is such that for every $p\in M$ the map $f(p,\cdot)\colon N \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and for every $q\in N$ the map $f(\cdot,q)\colon M\to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. Does it follow that $f$ is a holomorphic function on $M\times N$?

This does hold away from the singular set of $M$ and $N$, so that $f$ should at least immediately be a weakly holomorphic function. Can it be shown to be strongly holomorphic?